# Java EE persistence query for array list

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, arraylist, entity

I have a method that returns an array list.

```
public ArrayList<Myuser> getList(String address) {

    javax.persistence.Query query;

    query = em.createNamedQuery("Myuser.findByAddress").setParameter("address", address);
    ArrayList<Myuser> daoList = (ArrayList<Myuser>) query.getResultList();

    return daoList;
}
```

The method is supposed to return an array list of all Myuser objects whose "address" attribute matches with the string "address". However it does not seem to be working.

I basically want to know how I can use the string that has been passed in and query it against all Myuser objects with the same address and get a result list from that.

Here is the Myuser class if required:

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Patrick
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYUSER")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findByUserid", query = "SELECT m FROM 
Myuser m WHERE m.userid = :userid")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findByName", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m 
WHERE m.name = :name")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findByPassword", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser 
m WHERE m.password = :password")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findByEmail", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m 
WHERE m.email = :email")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findByPhone", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m 
WHERE m.phone = :phone")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findByAddress", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m 
WHERE m.address = :address")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findBySecqn", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m 
WHERE m.secqn = :secqn")
, @NamedQuery(name = "Myuser.findBySecans", query = "SELECT m FROM Myuser m 
WHERE m.secans = :secans")})

public class Myuser implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "USERID")
private String userid;
@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password;
@Column(name = "EMAIL")
private String email;
@Column(name = "PHONE")
private String phone;
@Column(name = "ADDRESS")
private String address;
@Column(name = "SECQN")
private String secqn;
@Column(name = "SECANS")
private String secans;

public Myuser() {
}

public Myuser(String userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}

public String getUserid() {
    return userid;
}

public void setUserid(String userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getSecqn() {
    return secqn;
}

public void setSecqn(String secqn) {
    this.secqn = secqn;
}

public String getSecans() {
    return secans;
}

public void setSecans(String secans) {
    this.secans = secans;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (userid != null ? userid.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Myuser)) {
        return false;
    }
    Myuser other = (Myuser) object;
    if ((this.userid == null && other.userid != null) || (this.userid != null && !this.userid.equals(other.userid))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "entity.Myuser[ userid=" + userid + " ]";
}
```

}

Comment: "doesnt seem to be working" ? Care to share what that means? because the SQL query invoked will be in the LOG for your JPA provider, and that will tell you what happens